# System.NullReferenceException:

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

```
String ^one_word;
String ^Two_word;
int one_index = 0;
String^ copysword1 = one_word;
String^ Word;
one_word = this->textBox1->Text;
Two_word = this->textBox2->Text;
Word = copysword1->Insert(copysword1->Length, Convert::ToString(copysword1[one_index])); // Вставляет в конец строки символ
Word = copysword1->Remove(copysword1[one_index]);
```

Вызываю insert хочу поместить возвращаемое значение, на сколько понимаю систем строки в переменную типа систем строки, а потом его удалить, то есть будет строка 45 и 54, insert должен сделать 454, remove вернет 54,так как функции только возвращают, а не меняют исходную строку помещаю в переменную. Как исправить ошибку?

1. Чем отличается ссылка на объект и на его экземпляр?
2. Разрабатываются ли какие либо приложения с помощью winforms или на какой синтаксис он похож? Не понимаю для чего вуз меня с этим мучает, препод запретил использовать маршалинг, сказал пишите через функции которые работают с этим типом, std::string для вас в winforms не существует:(

Путём просмотра дебаггера с нескольких попыток я заметил что суть проблемы на сколько я понял в строке `String^ copysword1 = one_word;`
но не понимаю почему, в переменную того же класса мы знаком = говорим чтобы она присвоило такое же значение, но этого не происходит, не понимаю почему..

Comment: Так же как работает Remove? у нее 2 перегрузки, с 1 значением удаляет с выбранного индекса до конца строки на сколько я понимаю, с 2 значениями от выбранного до выбранного. открываю документацию windows string s = "abc---def"; Console.WriteLine("3)     {0}", s.Remove(3, 3));3)     abcdef удалило все дефисы, хотя по идее как я понимаю должен был удалить дефис под индексом 3 и на нем же остановиться, как все сложно.. Заранее благодарю всех причастных к моей проблеме за помощь

Comment: WinForms используют, приложения на нём разрабатывают. Но на языке C#. | А вот язык C++/CLI для разработки приложений не используют. Мучают им вас зря.

Comment: `String ^one_word;` - здесь переменная не определена, т. е. равна `null`. Здесь `String^ copysword1 = one_word;` в другую переменную присваивается `null`. Здесь `copysword1->Insert`, что неудивительно, возникает `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: В .NET строки копируются и сравниваются _по значению_.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Да уже догадался, просто не последовательное расположение строчек кода, там еще прикол был в Remove copysword1[one_index] вызывал ошибку, нужно было просто сделать счетчик и подставлять значение туда, а не пихать символ который еще и индексировался в коде, задачу написал, 5 утра можно ложится спать:) Спасибо за ответ.